# К какому слову относится определение?

Tags: пунктуация

К чему относится определение "с добавлением" в предложениях типа "Вафли из пшеничной муки(,) с добавлением вина" (вафли с добавлением вина или мука с добавлением вина?); "Хлеб, вырабатываемый по ГОСТ(,) из муки пшеничной(,) с добавлением молока" (хлеб с добавлением молока или мука с добавлением молока?)?

Answer (score 4):

"Вафли (какие?) из пшеничной муки (какие? как изготовленные?) с добавлением вина" - понятно, что это вафли **изготовлены** из пшеничной муки с добавлением вина. Значит, определение относится к слову "вафли", а вообще к предполагаемому причастию "изготовленные";

"Хлеб, вырабатываемый по ГОСТ из муки пшеничной с добавлением молока". "с добавлением молока" распространяет причастный оборот. Вырабатываемый (как?) по ГОСТ (из чего?) из муки (какой?) пшеничной (как?) с добавлением молока.

Так что запятые здесь не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо, я так правильно поняла, что запятые должны быть расставлены следующим образом в предложении типа "изделия, вырабатываемые по ГОСТ из пшеничной муки с добавлением молока, массой 0,1 кг, квадратной формы, с тремя или четырьмя притисками, поверхность посыпана пряностями (здесь уже масса, форма, притиски относятся к изделиям? И во втором предложении нельзя ли так задать вопросы: "Хлеб, (какой?) вырабатываемый по ГОСТ, (какой?) из муки пшеничной с добавлением молока.

Comment: Было бы возможно, если б второе определение стояло перед причастным оборотом:"Хлеб из пшеничной муки ,  вырабатываемый по ГОСТ с добавлением молока" . Иначе появляется двусмысленность, о которой Вы и говорите: непонятно, что к чему относится.